# Oracle Query giving error

Tags: sql, oracle

I m running below query in toad to test the result but I am getting error as

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no, 'ABC' isnullcheck,
               TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_in vehicleindate_time,
               TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_out vehicleoutdate_time,
            gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno,
            gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight,
               TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || challan_no challandate_no,
            remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in
       FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv,
            xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd,
            xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms
      WHERE gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type
        AND sv.project_id = 1368
        AND (sv.audit_flag IS NULL OR sv.audit_flag = 'N') UNION SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no, 'XYZ' portfolio,
               TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_in vehicleindate_time,
               TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_out vehicleoutdate_time,
            gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno,
            gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight,
               TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || challan_no challandate_no,
            remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in
       FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv,
            xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd,
            xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms
      WHERE gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type
        AND sv.project_id = 1368
        AND sv.audit_flag IS NULL
   ORDER BY isnullcheck, date_in DESC, vehicle_no UNION
              SELECT NULL, 0, 'ABC', NULL, NULL, NULL,
                     'ABC', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
                FROM DUAL
              UNION
              SELECT NULL, 0, 'XYZ', NULL, NULL, NULL,
                     'XYZ', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
                FROM DUAL
```

kindly suggest what is wrong here

Comment: Put `ORDER BY` at the end: **SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... ORDER BY ...**

Comment: @lad2025: tried, getting error as `ORA-00904: "ISNULLCHECK": invalid identifier`

Comment: @lad2025: I tried at the end by as **ORDER BY 2** but getting error as `ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two larger SELECTS (the first 2) are returning 12 items. The last two SELECTS (the small ones) are returning 13 items. UNION must have matching columns.

eg statement should end...

```
SELECT NULL, 0, 'ABC', NULL, NULL, NULL,
'ABC', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM DUAL

UNION

SELECT NULL, 0, 'XYZ', NULL, NULL, NULL,
'XYZ', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Kindly help the same thing with the query.

Comment: Remove the last `NULL` from each of the final `SELECT .. FROM DUAL`s

Comment: removed still getting error as `ORA-00904: "ISNULLCHECK": invalid identifier`

Comment: Replace `ORDER BY isnullcheck, date_in DESC, vehicle_no` with `ORDER BY 3, date_in DESC, vehicle_no`

Comment: replaced with that but getting error as `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` at **SELECT NULL, 0, 'ABC',....**

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Did you have a trailing comma somewhere or something?

Comment: yup, I resolved the issue with some changes. ! cant post the query here as it is very long